# python pickle string in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm having a hard time using multiprocessing in python, though I have not used much multiprocessing in any platform and do not have clear idea of how  queues work in multi-process communication. (If anyone could provide a simple reference, that will be big help).

Coming to problem:

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor

class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bla_exec = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    def blafunc(self,stt):
        print('sdasdadadsa::::::::',stt)

    def on_ticks(self,  ticks):
        f=self.bla_exec.submit(self.blafunc,ticks)
        print(f.result()) //If I dont do .result(), nothing gets printed
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sample().on_ticks('123')
```

This gives me error:

> ```
> TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
> ```

Note that I knowingly doing `f.result()` just to test my sample.

Comment: please give the full code

Comment: Do you know what `weakref` is?

Comment: @Steve, no but I don't think making a string is weakref in python. is it?

Comment: I think what it's doing is trying to pickle the `ProcessPoolExecutor` because the function you're trying to run in the pool is a bound method. The object it is bound to is a `Sample` that includes a reference to your `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  If I create the `ProcessPoolExecutor` as a top-level object not in the class, your code runs fine.

Comment: @Steve, yep it works after moving executor outside class but why does it try to pickle it anyway? I think I should read on bound methods in py. Also, it's still pickling the whole Sample object because of self in blafunc, no?

Comment: Exactly.  You answered your own question.  It's because of that 'self' that it has to come along to exist when `blafunc` is called.  I guess I'm not sure what you're saying, because you seem to both answer your own question and still be confused about why it's trying to serialize `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Steve , yep also works fine if I put staticmethod on top of blafunc and call it statically.  Dont know if python is genius or stupid. Thanks man for this.

Comment: It always serializes so that it can guarantee the same behavior if it runs your function in the same process space as if it decides to run it on another machine over the network.  It won't do that in the normal setup, but it can be made to do so I think.  Basically, it never relies on two processes being able to share memory, even if the OS can support that.

Comment: Wonder if I should make this stuff an answer...

Comment: @Steve, gotcha. So is it general practice to use staticmethod or simple pickable classes  for submitting to ProcessPoolExecutor ?

Comment: @steve, make it an answer. will accept it right away.

Comment: ok, I did that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think what it's doing is trying to pickle the ProcessPoolExecutor because the function you're trying to run in the pool is a bound method. The object it is bound to is a Sample that includes a reference to your ProcessPoolExecutor. If I create the ProcessPoolExecutor as a top-level object not in the class, your code runs fine.

Python serializes (pickles, by default) objects moved back and forth between the process spaces rather than relying on any kind of shared memory that might be possible between two processes.  So you have to be careful what your function has access to that Python has to bring along into the other process your function will run in.